# what is different between using Variable and not in Mariadb?

Tags: mariadb

I just want to get some hint. Is there a type issue?

issue case.

```
SET @ids = '4094,8562,11144,3017,5815,11121,1957,4095,8563,11145,3018,5816,8527,11122,1959,4096,8564,3020,5817,8528,11123,1961,4097,8571,3021,6020,8535,11128,1962,5181,8572,3581,6021';
```

this @ids value is actually collected by GROUP_CONCAT() from the subquery;

```
        SELECT 
            ifnull(sum(case when a.student IS NOT NULL then total END), 0)
        from 
            tb_class a
        WHERE 
            a.id IN (@ids) 
            and a.date >= '2023-02-01'  AND a.DATE <= '2023-02-02'
```

==> 0

correct case2.

```
SELECT 
    ifnull(sum(case when a.student IS NOT NULL then total END), 0)
from 
    tb_class a
WHERE 
    a.id IN (4094,8562,11144,3017,5815,11121,1957,4095,8563,11145,3018,5816,8527,11122,1959,4096,8564,3020,5817,8528,11123,1961,4097,8571,3021,6020,8535,11128,1962,5181,8572,3581,6021) 
    and a.date >= '2023-02-01'  AND a.DATE <= '2023-02-02'
```

==> 54

Comment: I'm not familiar with mariadb at all, but it looks like the issue is that `@ids` is storing a string, while the second example is a list of values. (if we don't automatically convert datatypes) The number `1` is not in the string `"1,2,3,4"` but it is in the list `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: I got answer from googling. use function FIND_IN_SET() ex) ~~ where FIND_IN_SET(a.id, @ids) and ~~ Cheers  Samathingamajig.

Comment: Depending on how the `@id` list was generated, the alternate is to create a temporary table and `JOIN` that to the other table.

Answer (score 1):

I got answer from googling. use function FIND_IN_SET()

```
        SELECT 
            ifnull(sum(case when a.student IS NOT NULL then total END), 0)
        from 
            tb_class a
        WHERE 
            FIND_IN_SET(a.id, @ids) 
            and a.date >= '2023-02-01'  AND a.DATE <= '2023-02-02'
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables store single values, not lists.    Your `@ids` is just a string that happens to have a comma separated list of numbers.  The IN operator only compares against an explicit list; what you are doing is no different than `a.id = @ids` (which will actually be true, with a warning, for the first number in the list if id is a numeric type, since the string will be converted to a number and the trailing non-numeric portion discarded).

Sometimes you do want to work with a string containing a list of ids such as this, for instance if you have a query that reads many rows that you want to use to produce a small list of ids to update, without the update locking those all the rows read.  Then you can use dynamic sql:

```
SET @ids = '4094,8562,...';
SET @sql = concat('select * from a where a.id in (',@ids,')');
prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

Or, in mariadb since 10.2,

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE concat('select * from a where a.id in (',@ids,')');
```

Another alternative is to use FIND_IN_SET, as shown in another answer, but that will not use an index to look up ids, so may be inefficient.

Comment: So save the `prepare stmt; execute stmt; deallocate prepare stmt` cycle MariaDB has [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE concat('select * from a where a.id in (',@ids,')')'](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/execute-immediate/).